# Ruby 2.1.7 vs 2.2.3 garbage collection

Tags: ruby, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm seeing some weird potentially ruby 2.2.3 gc-related issues with generating a prefix tries from a list of words.  The suspect code is here:

```
def insert(word)
      return if word.nil? || word.empty?
      node = self
      counter = 0
      l = word.length
      #TODO _ why is this not being garbage collected?
      word.bytes.each do |i|
        counter += 1
        node.children[i] ||= Node.new(i.chr, node, counter == l)
        node = node.children[i]
        node.terminal = true if counter == l
      end
    end
```

It's being called from a list of strings - as such

```
words.each_with_index do |word, i|
    @root.insert(word)
```

When I do some memory profiling on this, I see the total mem usage in ruby 2.2.3-railsexpress **as ~68MB:**

```
Measure Mode: memory
Thread ID: 70102347546980
Fiber ID: 70102348363420
Total: 68688.375000
Sort by: self_time

 %self      total      self      wait     child     calls  name
 20.03  13755.000 13755.000     0.000     0.000   293398   FastAutocomplete::Node#initialize
  9.05   6218.875  6218.875     0.000     0.000    86036   String#bytes
  6.26  66665.562  4298.438     0.000 62367.125    86040  *Array#each
  1.50   1028.969  1028.969     0.000     0.000   230540   Hash#keys
  0.98    677.219   676.438     0.000     0.781        1   Array#map
```

When I used 2.1.7, **I only see about 22MB usage:**

```
    Measure Mode: memory
Thread ID: 70216772377340
Fiber ID: 70216782765400
Total: 22009.125000
Sort by: self_time

 %self      total      self      wait     child     calls  name
 62.49  13754.391 13754.391     0.000     0.000   293398   FastAutocomplete::Node#initialize
 28.25   6218.641  6218.641     0.000     0.000    86036   String#bytes
  4.67   1028.078  1028.078     0.000     0.000   230540   Hash#keys
  3.07    676.797   676.203     0.000     0.594        1   Array#map
  1.27    280.203   280.203     0.000     0.000   116093   Thread::Queue#enq
  0.07     19.297    15.516     0.000     3.781        9   JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Hash#to_json
```

I've tried multiple things like tracking GC.stats throughout the creation process, but haven't noticed anything particularly telling.  I've also tried using string.each_char or string.split('').each (i.e. different iterators).

Any ideas as to why 2.2.3 is using 3x the memory?  This is causing some of our servers to blow up.